# Hide scrollbar during splash animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

So I have a site where I created a splash screen.
It's quite a simple code

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;"> Something<div>
```

It has additional style for animation, so it would appear and then slide to the top after people see it:

```
-webkit-animation-name: splash;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes splash
{
0%
{
    bottom:0;
}
33%
{
bottom:0;
}
100%
{
    bottom:100%;
}
```

And what I want to do, is make the scrollbar disappear from the webpage during the animation. I'm no good at javascript, so first I'm asking is there a way to do it in CSS? If there isn't could anyone help me with a script that would put `overflow: hidden;` in my html tag and remove it after the animations? 
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this css:

```
body, html{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and this JS:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$('html,body').css('overflow','auto');}, 5000);
});
```

*Also, just as a note your current code would not animate. You have not assigned the animation to the div*

Comment: I know, haven't pasted all of the code in here, I hate putting those 4 spaces :D. I'll try this in an hour or so and check in if it works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure am I using JSfiddle correctly, but I added the code and it doesn't seem to work. Check it out if you can, please. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLY7q/11/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery on the left side of jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLY7q/16/

Comment: Oh, for some reason I believed this is simple JavaScript. Have to admit that I'm not really familiar with them a lot. Thanks! One more question, is there any difference what version of jquery I'll use? I see you didn't select the newest one.

Comment: @user2647359 You're welcome. Also, no there isn't a difference between the versions of jQuery you select, at least not for the code I provided. I'm not sure why I didn't originally select the newest one, was probably too tired to think straight :p. However, I do recommend you stick with the 1.x versions, as the 2.x versions don't support IE8 or below. Also, if I have answered your question, please tick the check next to the post to mark it as answer. Thx :)